# Python requests - Tumblr photo upload

Tags: python, request, python-requests

I want to use Python's requests module to upload photos to tumblr. I have sucessfully logged in, and made some POST method, there is only one error (I got near to the end of upload process):

```
session.headers = {'referer': 'https://www.tumblr.com/blog/myblogname/new/photo',
                'User-Agent': ua,
                'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                'x-tumblr-form-key': form_key}

files ={image_to_post : open(image_to_post,mode="r")}

post_photo = session.post('https://www.tumblr.com/svc/post/upload_photo',    headers =session.headers, cookies=cookie, files = files )
```

The payload what tumblr post method requires:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryORrQGzdK9p9jH0Aq
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo"; filename="nameofimage.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryORrQGzdK9p9jH0Aq--
```

What could be the good format for that WebKitForm?

The problem is with the file opening/choosing, because if I add bad data, like a url or something, it says: It's nice but it isn't a photo in a right format please save it into jpg/png etc etc.

The current response:

```
{"errors":["Please select a photo file to upload."],"post":false}
```

Comment: Do you use `files ={image_to_post : open(image_to_post,mode="r")}` in your request? It's obviously should be `files={'photo': open(image_to_post, "rb")}`

Comment: Thank you! I made through it myself.
The correct code is :
  files ={"photo": ("nameofphoto.jpg",open(image_to_post,"rb"))}''